# .apk file being sent as .zip

Tags: android, android-studio, zip, apk

I am a newbie in Android development and recently have shifted to macOS. I want to share my Android apk to my friend via web WhatsApp but in place of .apk file, it is being sent as a .zip file. I have used the following steps to trace my apk file.

```
Build -> Build Bundle(s)/APK(s) -> Build APK(s) -> locate
```

After which I was redirected to app-debug.apk which I shared via web.whatsapp. This procedure worked perfectly well in my old Ubuntu PC (Browser: Mozilla) but after shifting to macOS (Browser: Safari), it is being shared as .zip file. Please help me figure out that how can I share a .apk file?

P.s. I am attaching screenshots for the same.

### Ideal (Sent from Ubuntu)

[image: Screenshot of apk]

### Current (Sent from macOS)

[image: Screenshot of zip]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use this https://wetransfer.com/  or you can use this https://www.diawi.com/ to share the apk file

Comment: Thanks @Amitpandey it worked.